# Power BI table visual doesn't work for only one person - how do I debug?

Tags: powerbi

I have a report that doesn't do anything fancy. Has multiple tabs and some tables and graphs on each. Fully in import mode, using a data gateway. Everything is green and connected and refreshing successfully.

One table on the first page does not work for one specific person, but it works for me (the original designer) and for other employees who have access.

I tried clearing his cache and temporary files to see if that would help. I really have no idea what to check. The error is fairly cryptic and basically says it couldn't connect to the data source - but why? We're all on the same network.

Here's the other thing. If I go into edit mode on the problem PC and modify something on the table, it loads immediately. I save the report and as soon as I switch back to reading view, the same problem happens. So clearly he is able to access the data.

I'm a little stuck on this one - any help is appreciated.

How do I figure out what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well, we still don't know why it happened, but the user decided to click "Reset to Defaults" and it magically fixed the issue. Who knows what he had done to cause this. Maybe this will help the next person!